# Theorem 8.25 (Ratio Test) - Proof of part b), Mathematical Analysis 2nd ed. - Apostol

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Theorem 8.25 (Ratio Test)** Given a series $\sum a_n$ of nonzero complex terms, let

$$r=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left |\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\qquad R=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left |\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| $$

b) The series $\sum a_n$ diverges if $r>1$.

*Proof*. To prove b), *Apostol says*, we simply observe that r>1 implies $|a_{n+1}|>|a_n|$ for all $n\ge N$ for some $N$ and hence we cannot have $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

How are the following two sentences related?

1. The series $\sum a_n$ diverges if $r>1$.
2. "we cannot have $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$".

Should 2 imply 1?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) does imply (1), by a simple boundedness argument.

Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n}\neq 0$.  Then there exist countably many terms such that $a_n\geq b$ or $a_n\leq b$ for some $b\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.  Without loss of generality assume we have countably many terms with $a_n\geq b>0$ and let these terms be labeled as $b_n$ (note this is a subsequence of $a_n$).  Then, regarding the sum, we have
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}\geq\sum_{k-0}^{\infty}{b_k}\geq\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{b}
\end{equation}

Ans since $b$ is constant, the final sum is unbounded, so $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}$ is unbounded.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

We know that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$$

is a necessary, though not sufficient, condition for the convergence of the series $\;\sum a_n\;$ , so what Apostol says is obvious.

What you ask is unrelated: we can have that $\;\sum a_n\;$ diverges and still $\;r=1\;$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\;$. For example, with the harmonic series.

Comment: So if we cannot have $lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ this means that we lack a necessary condition for the convergence of the series $\sum a_n$. For this reason the series $\sum a_n$ diverges and point b) is proved. Am I right? Thank you for your time, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, that's right, @Charlie